# Access servers http via VPN

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, vpn, wireguard

I have 2 VPS. On one of VPS lets call it A i setup Wireguard vpn. I connected my second VPS as peer to VPS A, also im connecting as client to Wireguard and cant access any web via local vpn address on server B.
Nginx logs shows that server B took my request but it doesnt respond to me. Also nc -vz command succeeded.
How can i fix that? Curl / web-browser does not show anything

```
Server A: iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 45630 packets, 6884K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 64284 packets, 111M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                    
   38 11371 ACCEPT     all  --  wg-172 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 92761 packets, 119M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination   

ip r:
default via 1.1.1.1(public ip) dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/8 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
1.1.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 1.1.1.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002 
172.16.0.0/24 dev wg-172 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.1
```

```
tcpdump on vpn interface from my laptop

tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on utun3, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes

18:19:16.483263 IP 172.16.0.3.49685 > 172.16.0.2.http: Flags [S], seq 2006555320, win 65535, options [mss 1380,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 666581156 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
18:19:16.626234 IP 172.16.0.2.http > 172.16.0.3.49685: Flags [S.], seq 2191963124, ack 2006555321, win 27360, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 366766758 ecr 666581156,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:19:16.626348 IP 172.16.0.3.49685 > 172.16.0.2.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 666581299 ecr 366766758], length 0
18:19:16.626442 IP 172.16.0.3.49685 > 172.16.0.2.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:75, ack 1, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 666581299 ecr 366766758], length 74: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
18:19:16.770856 IP 172.16.0.2.http > 172.16.0.3.49685: Flags [.], ack 75, win 214, options [nop,nop,TS val 366766902 ecr 666581299], length 0
18:19:16.770866 IP 172.16.0.2.http > 172.16.0.3.49685: Flags [P.], seq 4105:5074, ack 75, win 214, options [nop,nop,TS val 366766902 ecr 666581299], length 969: HTTP
18:19:16.771006 IP 172.16.0.3.49685 > 172.16.0.2.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 666581444 ecr 366766902,nop,nop,sack 1 {4105:5074}], length 0
18:19:18.237977 IP 172.16.0.3.49685 > 172.16.0.2.http: Flags [R.], seq 75, ack 1, win 2052, length 0
```